# Regex to get only the uppercase words in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am new to Perl and I have been doing a few assignments.

I have a file `abc.txt`. It contains `The Bad boy and Good Boy both Went to School`.

I have to write a program to open the file and print only the words that start with uppercase letters.

Below is my program

```
my $a = "abc.txt";
open(my $fh,$a) or die "cannot open: $!\n";
while(<$fh>) {
    // I need to add the regex here
    if ($_ =~ /#REGEX HELP PLEASE/)
        # The regex should be generic. The line can change in the file
}
```

Comment: `perldoc perlre` might help.

Answer (score 1):

```
use warnings;
use strict; 

my @array = qw(The Bad boy and Good Boy both Went to School);

foreach (@array){
    if ($_ =~ /([A-Z][a-z])/){ 
        print "$_\n"
    }
}
```

Or, more simply:

```
foreach (@array){
    print "$_\n" if /([A-Z][a-z])/;
}
```

Comment: It prints only one word `The `

Comment: @Newbie - no it doesn't.

Comment: There is only one line in the file . 
Let is be like ` $a = "The Bad boy and Good Boy both Went to School";`

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -lne 'push @a,/\b([A-Z][a-z0-9]+)\b/g;END{print join "\n",@a}' your_file
```

Tested:

```
> cat temp
hello world.
This is hello world.
Another hello world.
New hello World.
The Bad boy and Good Boy both Went to School
>
> perl -lne 'push @a,/\b([A-Z][a-z0-9]+)\b/g;END{print join "\n",@a}' temp
This
Another
New
World
The
Bad
Good
Boy
Went
School
>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work.

```
my $a = "abc.txt";
open(my $fh,$a) or die "cannot open: $!\n";
while(<$fh>) {
    my @b = split(' ',$_);
    foreach my $c (@b){
        if ($c =~ /([A-Z]\w+)/) {
            print "$1\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
while(<$fh>) {
    my @words = split/\W+/,$_;
    foreach (@words) {
        print if /^[A-Z]\w+/;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex you need is `/\b[A-Z]+\S*\b/g` but you probably need to change the code a bit as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
open(my $fl, 'abc.txt');
while(<$fl>) {
    my @array = split(' ', $_);
    my @results = grep(/([A,Z]\w+)/, @array);
}
```

Grep will return a list with elements of `@array` which match the expression.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `abc.txt` contains the line (string) "The Bad boy and Good Boy both Went to School.", you can do the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $fileName = 'abc.txt';

open my $fh, '<', $fileName or die $!;

while (<$fh>) {
    print $1, "\n" while /([A-Z]\w+)/g;
}

close $fh;
```

Output:

```
The
Bad
Good
Boy
Went
School
```

Hope this helps!